# How do I assert a `number` type is an integer?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have the following function:

```
function repeat(times: number, cb: (index: number) => any) {
    for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        cb(i);
    }
}

repeat(3, (i) => console.log(i)); // logs 0 1 2
```

I want to be able to assert at compile-time that the given number for the number of times to call the callback is an integer.  I know that you can do this by taking in a `bigint`, however, I would rather not allow for numbers to be larger than the regular `number` limit because the function would most likely not even finish.  Is there any way to make TypeScript error when the number provided is not an integer?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this via some awesome string intrinsic behavior with the `number` and `bigint` type.  Basically, the `${bigint}` template literal type matches any sign (+ / -) optional followed by one or more digits.  Now, when you take any `number` type and interpolate it into a template literal like the following: `${5}` it gets normalized into a regular string type like this `"5"`.  Therefore, we can take the stringified form of the number and check if it extends the `${bigint}` type.  If so, then make the parameter type itself.  Otherwise, make it `never` and thus force the user to change their type.

```
type AssertInteger<N extends number> =
  number extends N ? N : `${N}` extends `${bigint}` ? N : never;

function repeat<N extends number>(times: AssertInteger<N>, cb: (index: number) => any) {
    for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        cb(i);
    }
}

// dummy function
const dummy = (_: number) => {};

// No Errors 
repeat(1, dummy);
repeat(543.0, dummy);
repeat(-43, dummy);
repeat(0, dummy);
repeat(5e5, dummy);
repeat(0.01e3, dummy);

// Correctly errors 
repeat(1.2, dummy);
repeat(-0.9, dummy);
repeat(543.5, dummy);
repeat(-43.8, dummy);
repeat(-43e-1, dummy);
```

The `number extends N ? N` clause of the `AssertInteger` type is just a little check to see if the `number` type is an exact number type. If it's inexact (`number`), then we will simply let the integer go through because there would be no way to assert it besides some ugly casts.

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggznCAnYBJAdsCBzZAeAOSggA8t0ATOKdAVwFsAjZAPigF4aHmliyJK1IgH4oRAFxQABgBIA3gQC+UvuSrT5jAJbYtmZVFESaEAG7IA3AFgAULYBmtdAGNgWgPbooSCJACGwISqAup0TKwAFG70EHCS8IgoGFi4SIQsADRQzoySEXoUpJJhPACUHGx+6CDlcrZQDVD27rwRADYQwFBaHFAADBbdUHhQ0bGDWgDUk7X1jfM5+aXWNvOKtut2NgD021AUDPQgTU6uHui2zp5wXQf0R70RAPrF3Mjl7Gxyiiu2u2LuKAAUSQSBa1EAPBuASP3bD5-MAIgBGLJ3I7LWG+CABCIAVgALABmAB0fRRhxqKzhWIRAFpCWT7hSMfCIqT9uT0TYqdicRAcQy0ZTMdi+iTERACQKmVt-gBhFo+VxtY7IMFISEwrnChGIokAJilnO5tNFAE5DUKWfjifz2YyjdqInTiQAOC3M6lOwkQGnIu2CoA)

Comment: This is very interesting. I have a question though. What is the purpose of the `number extends N ? N : ` part of `AssertInteger`? It seems to me this is redundant? Except for `number` itself no type could ever satisfy this condition right? Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation of what is the process of arriving at the type definition, so many people just write down some crazy TypeScript logic without explain how it works